# Understanding htaccess redirect to HTTPS and WWW

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have some questions about a code I found on stackoverflow. The code does what I want to do. Redirects to HTTPS and WWW when doesn't exist in URL. But, I want now to understand what I'm doing.

So, here is the code I use:

```
# Redirect non HTTPS to HTTPS #
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force www #
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,E=HTTPS:1]
```

1. The code above works as expected. Why isn't the code in the next format, as it does the same thing ? Is any difference ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

2. The first line of code looks a little bit ambiguous. So I try to modify with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on # Put a space before on
```

Or:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != 'on' # Put on in single quotes
```

Or:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != "on" # Put on in double quotes
```

And it doesn't work. Can you please explain why ?

3. I found some users which are using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

and not:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

I understand that one line checks if the https is off and another one if https is not on. We can say they do the same thing. There are other differences here ? Can HTTPS not be neither `on` or `off` ? If the answer is yes, that means the line `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` is better than `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`. Isn't it ?

4 When forcing www I have `E=HTTPS:1` flag, which means I set the variable HTTPS with value 1. I don't understand the reason... When and who checks for this variable ?

Here, on question 4 I try to rename HTTPS to HTTPSaaa and then, with php, to get all server variable (from $_SERVER). I don't find HTTPSaaa. So this means that the flag is used only by htaccess ? So, I ask again. What's the reason for this flag/variable to exist ?

PS: If someone want's to answer, please specify the question number. I am already a little bit confused...

Comment: We require that the poster know why the code is written the way it is. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: If this question is off-topic for CodeReview then feel free to ask future questions of this nature (or even move this question) to the [Webmasters stack](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), where it is certainly on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. The code above works as expected. Why isn't the code in the next format, as it does the same thing? Is any difference ?
>
>    ```
>    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
>    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
>    ```

This code is different to your "working" code (at the top of your question). In this code, the `www` subdomain is *always* prefixed to the requested hostname. So, if you were to request `http://www.example.com/foo` (HTTP + www) then it will redirect to `https://www.www.example.com/foo` - which is presumably not the intention.

This can be "fixed" with an additional *condition* in order to capture the hostname less the "optional" `www` subdomain, however, this is still not "the same" as the "working" directives you posted. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The only purpose of the 3rd *condition* is to capture the hostname, less the `www.` prefix (if any). This condition is *always* successful. The hostname (less the `www.` prefix) is stored in the `%1` backreference.

Just to emphasise... this is not *exactly* the same as the "working" redirects you posted initially. This performs the HTTPS + www redirect in 1 go, instead of two (potentially) in your "working" directives. eg. When you request HTTP and non-www then your "working" redirects will trigger 2 redirects, first to HTTPS on the same host<sup>***1**</sup> and then to HTTPS + www.

<sup>***1**</sup> This is a necessary requirement if you have implemented [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) - where you must redirect to HTTPS on the same host *before* canonicalising the hostname. So, one redirect is not always "better" than two.

> 2. The first line of code looks a little bit ambiguous. So I try to modify with:
>
>    ```
>    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on # Put a space before on
>    ```

It may *look* ambiguous to you, but I assure you it's not.

You cannot simply inject spaces here, since *spaces* are argument delimiters in Apache config files. So, by putting a *space* after the `!=` you are now passing 3 arguments to the `RewriteCond` directive: `%{HTTPS}`, `!=` and `on`. `on` is likely to trigger an "invalid flags" error, since this will be interpreted as the 3rd "flags" parameter (eg. normally something like `[NC]`).

The `=` and `!` are prefix-operators and are in fact part of the argument (*CondPattern*). They change the way the *CondPattern* (2nd argument) is interpreted. `!=` is not a single operator, it does not strictly mean not-equals, as you are perhaps expecting, although the net result is the same. (More on this below).

The only time you *need* to use double-quotes (not single-quotes) around an argument in Apache config files is if the argument contains *spaces* (since, as mentioned above, *spaces* are argument delimiters). Although you can always surround the argument in double-quotes if you wish. And you can sometimes backslash escape the *space* instead (if the argument is a regex).

But note, the double-quotes surround the *entire argument* (which includes the prefix operators). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} "!=on"
```

*Aside:* Apache does not support line-end comments, so the `# Put a space before on` at the end of the line is not valid. Due to the way Apache directives are processed, this may appear to be OK at times (ie. no error), but it is strictly invalid. (You may have only used this in the code sample in your question, however, it is a common source of error, so worth mentioning.)

> 3. I found some users which are using:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> ```
>
> and not:
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> ```
>
> I understand that one line checks if the https is off and another one if https is not on. We can say they do the same thing. There are other differences here ?

I've actually [answered the same question on the Webmasters stack](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/118396/1243) previously, so I'll just link to that for more detail:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118391/in-htaccess-files-is-there-any-difference-at-all-between-on-and-off

But yes, the net result is indeed the same and it's primarily personal preference which method you choose. Although the two methods are technically different.

- `off` is a regex comparison: Does `off` occur anywhere in the value of the `HTTPS` server variable?
- `!=on` is *not* a regex comparison. The `=` prefix changes it to a lexicographical string comparison. ie. Is the value of the HTTPS server var exactly equal to "on"? The `!` prefix then negates the expression. So the condition is successful when it does not match.

> Can `HTTPS` not be neither on or off ?

The `HTTPS` server variable can only be "on" or "off" if your server is correctly configured.

> If the answer is yes, that means the line `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` is better than `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`. Isn't it ?

Not necessarily. If `HTTPS` is not "on" or "off" then it's more likely to not be set at all (on all requests), so `!=on` would always be successful and result in a redirect loop. Whereas `off` will simply fail. Although this is hypothetical, your server would have to be "broken" for the `HTTPS` *server* variable not to be set at all and to not be "on" or "off".

> 4. When forcing www I have `E=HTTPS:1` flag, which means I set the variable HTTPS with value 1.

First, a bit of clarification... there are 2 variables here:

1. The `HTTPS` *server* variable as set by Apache and referenced in `%{HTTPS}`. This is effectively readonly.
2. The `HTTPS` *environment* variable that you are setting here. This would be readable using the syntax `%{ENV:HTTPS}`.

Whilst it is relatively common to see this, it is arguably confusing to have two different variables of the same name. It would be *better* to change your environment variable to something like `HSTS` instead (see below), to avoid any confusion.

> I don't understand the reason... When and who checks for this variable ?

Well, in the directives you posted it's not required. So, maybe this is not required here? But...

The reason for setting an env var on the HTTPS redirect like this is a common pattern when implementing HSTS<sup>***2**</sup>. When implementing HSTS you need to set the `Strict-Transport-Security` HTTP response header on the HTTPS to HTTPS redirect itself. This is why I suggested using a variable called `HSTS` instead. If you are not setting this header with a conditional `Header` directive elsewhere in your config file (based on this env var) then you are not implementing HSTS (properly) and this env var is most probably superfluous.

<sup>***2**</sup> Although I wouldn't necessarily do it this way myself. I would set the env var in a separate rule, since you still need to set the STS header on other HTTPS responses, not just the redirect. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/131970/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack for more information on this, with example code:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115125/hsts-implementation-when-using-www-tld

> Here, on question 4 I try to rename HTTPS to HTTPSaaa and then, with php, to get all server variable (from $_SERVER). I don't find HTTPSaaa. So this means that the flag is used only by htaccess ? So, I ask again. What's the reason for this flag/variable to exist ?

Yes, it's only used by Apache/`.htaccess`. It is set only on the redirect response back to the client. Your PHP script is not processed in this time, so cannot read it.

The reason would be to help with implementing HSTS, as described above.

---

If you are interested in HSTS then see this related CodeReview question (and [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251218/6744)) regarding the implementation of HSTS in `.htaccess`:

- [HSTS Recommendations in .htaccess](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250805/hsts-recommendations-in-htaccess)

Comment: Thank you, MrWhite! A wonderful answer and so clear!

Comment: [Please do not answer off-topic questions.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @greybeard Sorry, but I didn't realise it was off-topic at the time I answered.